# DRF serializer skips nested serializer validation when many=True

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a serializer which refers to another serializer with many=True. Simplified version:

```
class SerializerA(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.CharField()
    quantity = serializers.IntegerField()

class SerializerB(serializers.Serializer):
    name = serializers.CharField()
    items = SerializerA(many=True, required=True)
```

When I'm getting data without items field specified, serializer.is_valid() for some reason returns True. But if 'many' argument set to False, validation works as expected.

Why is that happening?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're trying to perform PUT or POST. In this case, DRF do not support nested relations out of the box and if you don't have anything in the field `items` - validator returns true. It should return an error if you will have something in the `items`.

To make POST/PUT work you need to override .create() and .update() method of the SerializerB.